# difference between generics and interfaces

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented-design

Are there any advantages of using generic type constraints over an interface?

For example:

```
T whatever<T>() where T is IInterface;
```

vs

```
IInterface whatever();
```

My guess is it's just a personal preference but it seems to be more about functional style vs object oriented style. The functional style being the generic type constraints.

Comment: These have decidedly different behaviors... You're going to need to elaborate why you think they are comparable.

Comment: `where T is IInterface` - what? `T` is a type parameter, it can be any type. Are you sure you understand what generics are?

Comment: Why would you be using an interface here? This is a circuitous way of going about it. If you need an interface you use an interface, and if you want to abstract a concrete type without losing information like with an interface you would use generics.

Comment: @scriptin In several languages generics can put bounds on the generic type parameters, which means that the generic can only be instantiated with types fulfilling certain constraints (such as implementing some interface). Since there's no language tag, I assume this is pseudo-code.

Comment: @scriptin - C# (and others) have the ability to place constraints on generics so that they can only be derivatives of a specified type.

Comment: [This seems related](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/276433/what-is-the-reason-of-using-an-interface-versus-a-generically-constrained-type)